# Why my SQL Function returns unexpected value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a function where I need to fetch Title(e.g. Mr/Miss/Mrs) FirstName and LastName from a table based on a comma delimited string containing user emails.

so far I have tried following

[My SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1ef5) **PS.** First build the schema on fiddler page and then try to executing queries

When i run following

```
select dbo.fn_getUserNamefrmEmail('abc.def@gmail.com')
```

I get proper output as `Mr. Abc Def`

but when i try to run

```
select dbo.fn_getToUserNames('abc.def@gmail.com, pqr.stu@gmail.com, xyz.mno@gmail.com, stu.v@gmail.com',',')
```

I am getting NULL - 0 as i have set result to 0 if it is NULL

I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong and need help.

Comment: +1 for preparing a fiddle. If everyone could do that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one small problem.

Change the line

```
DECLARE @result_string nvarchar(max)
```

to

```
DECLARE @result_string nvarchar(max) = ''
```

You haven't initialised @result_string variable so it remains null when you do

```
SELECT @result_string = @result_string + ', ' + @temp
```

And the end result is still null.

Correct version in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90052/1).